# Android App crashes on launch | IntelliJ Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

I just built my app and it started crashing without errors.
I don't know why.
I just rewrite the code from my testapp because there was missing 1 library file.

Here is my terminal :

```
   11/23 14:14:32: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t -p com.tomsovec.smart2t C:\Users\TomKo\Desktop\SmartLock2T\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk 
Split APKs installed in 3 s 186 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "com.tomsovec.smart2t/com.tomsovec.smart2t.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 10196 on device Nexus_5X_API_28 [emulator-5554]
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/omsovec.smart2: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
I/chatty: uid=10087(com.tomsovec.smart2t) identical 10 lines
W/omsovec.smart2: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/omsovec.smart2: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
I/omsovec.smart2: Background concurrent copying GC freed 25239(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 54% free, 1291KB/2MB, paused 1.439ms total 121.585ms
W/omsovec.smart2: JNI critical lock held for 19.414ms on Thread[1,tid=10196,Runnable,Thread*=0xe30f4000,peer=0x73a08760,"main"]
W/omsovec.smart2: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
W/omsovec.smart2: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
W/omsovec.smart2: Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic; (light greylist, linking)
W/omsovec.smart2: JNI critical lock held for 18.004ms on Thread[1,tid=10196,Runnable,Thread*=0xe30f4000,peer=0x73a08760,"main"]
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tomsovec.smart2t, PID: 10196
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.tomsovec.smart2t/com.tomsovec.smart2t.Login}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2005)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4905)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4873)
        at com.tomsovec.smart2t.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10196 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

At the beginning it didn't crash (only sometimes when I logged in using database

Answer (score 1):

The exception is self explanatory **ActivityNotFoundException**

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.tomsovec.smart2t/com.tomsovec.smart2t.Login}; 
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

> Unable to find explicit activity class, have you declared this
>   activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

So. Have you added this activity to your manifest?

```
<application
    ...
    <activity 
        android:name=".Login" >   
    </activity>  
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check you application's manifest.xml if you have set
`com.tomsovec.smart2t.Login`
as an activity.

The crash starts when you are trying to load your application.